# GWT Bean validation does not return all constraint violations in compiled mode

Tags: gwt, bean-validation, objectify

I am experiencing different behavior for client side bean validation when running in gwt development mode than in compiled mode. I have been trying to debug and resolve this issue for hours (days actually) but, although further still did not find the root cause and am currently stuck. Hence my request for help.

In general I have been following the approach advocated here http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html 
and was further more inspired by various articles and questions on StackOverlow. So I have the user enter an object on the client. Than I validate it client side via a call to the validator that has been created by the validator factory.

The problem I am experiencing is that when more than one constraint is validated (i.e. the user enters 2 or more "mistakes") the validator does not (always) return all constraint violations when running in compiled mode, while it does return them all when running in gwt development mode.

The object I try to validate is of the class `EnvyMonUser`

```
@Entity
public class EnvyMonUser implements Serializable, Obj<EnvyMonUser> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

@Id
private Long id;

@NotNull(message = "company must be selected")
@Index
private Key<Company> companyKey;

@Index
private String googleUserId;
@NotNull(message = "email address must be set")
@Pattern(regexp = EMAIL_PATTERN, message = "invalid email address")
@Index
private String email;
@NotNull(message = "name must be set")
@Size(min = 3, message = "must have a name of minimal 3 characters")
@Index
private String nickName;

@NotNull(message = "location must be selected")
@Index
private Key<SampleLocation> sampleLocationKey;

@NotNull(message = "result must be set")
@Index
private Long value;

...
```

Where `Company` and `SampleLocation` are two other classes. (The annotations @Entity, @Index, @Id and the class Key are of Objectify. I use the same entity class(es) client and server (gae) side. )

Once the user has entered an EnvyMonUser object I validate it via a validator, i.e.

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

...

EnvyMonUser obj = getView().getEditorDriver().flush();

Set<ConstraintViolation<O>> validate = validator.validate(obj);
```

where my validation factory is

```
public final class AppValidatorFactory extends AbstractGwtValidatorFactory {
@GwtValidation(value = { MonitorType.class, Measurement.class,
        ProgramMeasurement.class, EnvyMonUser.class, Company.class,
        SampleLocation.class })
public interface GwtValidator extends Validator {
}

@Override
public AbstractGwtValidator createValidator() {
    return GWT.create(GwtValidator.class);
}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Desperate as I was I tried removing and adding several fields but have not found any logical pattern. Depending on which fields I leave out and also on which of the fields are filled correctly by the user the (missing) constraint(s) in compiled mode change.

I have already tried multiple routes but no success so far. For example at some point I thought this was caused by using objectify. However when I remove `sampleLocationKey` member it works perfectly fine for companyKey member. I also tried removing the objectify attributes but this also doesn't seem to make a difference.

An interesting thing I did observe (by accident) is that when I remove (comment) some of the members from the `hashCode` and `equals` methods the behavior changes. Not sure why this is. Maybe it has something to do with how the validator generator is implemented.

Does anyone have any clue?

Also a pointer in the right direction is appreciated. Does someone for example know where I can find the validator that is generated. Or the sources of the validator generator?

Some versions of libraries I use:

- gwt 2.6.0
- hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
- hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final-sources.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- objectify 4.0.1

Comment: Contrary to what I said above, it does seem related to using objectify's `Key` class. For some reason if the `equals` method of `com.googlecode.objectify.Key` (which in practise is the `compareTo` of `com.google.appengine.api.datastore`) is involved the resulting validation isn't working correctly.

Could this be because of the transient `appIdNamespace` that is used in `compareToInternal` ?

Unfortunatly, no solution yet. So suggestions still more than welcome!

Comment: Found a possible bug in `com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.ConstraintViolationImpl` that could be causing this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/xRVGnMWfttc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not in my code but a bug in gwt sources for `com.google.gwt.validation.client.impl.ConstraintViolationImpl` . See  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/xRVGnMWfttc for a full description of the problem and solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The validations were working fine on dev mode and all the error messages were showing up on the UI but in the prod mode we could see only one error message at one time. Late on when  debugged and found that my DTO has implemented equals and hashcode method and that what causing this issue. The moment is removed these two implementations from my DTO every things worked fine after that.

I am using GWT 2.6.1.